# Правильная загрузка таблицы с БД без использование Merge и без использования Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

Исторически сложилось что мы пишем загрузки таблицы с бд только по процедурам и используем для этого стандартный SqlDataAdapter. Первым запросом мы получаем схему данных процедуры используя для этого пустые параметры - %имя процедуры/метода%(null). Если есть другой способ напишите.

Потом мы запрашиваем уже данные используя параметр, но объединяем с настоящей таблицей используя Merge чтобы добавлять данные если их нет в таблице.
Но часто запросы большие и мы их выносим в другой поток используя BackgroundWorker. Так как мы загрузили данные в другом потоке то приходится объединять данные в Dispatcher.

```
DataTable main = gettable(null);

void backgroundmethod(param)
{
    var dt = gettable(param);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => main.Merge(dt));

}
```

А эта самая таблица привязана к источнику данных DataGrid в интерфейсе и поэтому она и должна содержаться в главном потоке. У BackgroundWorker есть метод завершения работы возвращающий значения в главный поток, но некоторая проблема в том что таблицы может быть несколько и передача их как массив возвращаемых обьектов не кажется мне правильной.

```
void BWOnDoWork(object sender1, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    dt1 = getdata1(param1);    // метод возвращает готовую таблицу DataTable
    dt2 = getdata2(param2);
    doWorkEventArgs.result = new object[] {dt1, dt2};
}

void BWOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
{
    var params = runWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result as object[];
    maintable1.Merge(params[0]);
    maintable2.Merge(params[1]);
}
```

Можно ли как то упростить это дело?

Comment: `Но часто запросы большие и мы их выносим в другой поток используя BackgroundWorker` = используйте `Task.Run(...)` для такого, ожидайте результатов асинхронно, не придется морочиться с событиями BackgroundWorker

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо. Не догадались. У нас тут никто не может научить поэтому сочиняем.

Comment: Без проблем, все мы учимся. Если будут вопросы по коду, то этот сайт - самое подходящее место, где их можно задать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете начать вот с такого - последовательной загрузки данных

```
public async Task LoadData(object param1, object param2)
{
    var dt1 = await Task.Run(()=>getdata1(param1))
    var dt2 = await Task.Run(()=>getdata2(param2))

    maintable1.Merge(dt1);
    maintable2.Merge(dt2);
}
```

И далее, адаптировать пример под себя. Например, вы можете просто обе таблицы загрузить последовательно в одном таске, например

```
public async Task LoadData(object param1, object param2)
{
    DataTable dt1 = null;
    DataTable dt2 = null;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        dt1 = getdata1(param1);
        dt2 = getdata1(param1);
    });     

    maintable1.Merge(dt1);
    maintable2.Merge(dt2);
}
```

Или вы можете грузить данные параллельно

```
public async Task LoadData(object param1, object param2)
{
    var dt1task = Task.Run(() => getdata1(param1));
    var dt2task = Task.Run(() => getdata2(param2));

    await Task.WhenAll(dt1task, dt2task);   

    maintable1.Merge(dt1task.Result);
    maintable2.Merge(dt2task.Result);
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте снова, могу здесь спросить или лучше новый вопрос создать? у меня проблема с обращением к объектам из других потоков, не могу понять на каком объекте вылетает исключение потому что оно вылетает после завершения метода.

Comment: Если у вас новый вопрос, то задавайте его отдельно конечно.